# queria que os meus slides de apresentação apareçam só uma vez quando o app for instalado?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity

eu gostaria que quando o usuário terminasse de passar pelos slides do meu app automaticamente abriria uma nova activity e o slides fossem destruídos para não aparecerem mais eles apareceriam somente quando o app fosse instalado novamente se alguém souber de algum método?  abaixo vai o código que estou utilizando[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]! Por favor clique em **[edit]** e coloque o código como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052).

Answer (score 0):

O Ideal é que voce utilize as SharedPreferences para isso. Ao entrar no ecrã dos slides, voce deve salvar uma flag "ECRA_TAL_FOI_ABERTO" como true. E ao entrar na app, deve verificar se esse flag existe.

```
Boolean b = verificarSeExisteAFlag()
if(b){
    vaiParaEcraPrincipal()
}else{
    vaiParaEcraDeSlides()
}
```

Ao entrar nos slides voce devera:

```
salvarFlag(true)
```

As shared preferences são armazenadas enquanto a app estives instalada. E removidas quando o app é desisntalado.

**Referencias**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences